# Open ports and disable firewall from router D-link

Tags: port-forwarding, nat

I want to open and use the incoming ports from WAN to LAN: 443 (https), 1243 (mssql), 3306 (mysql), my firewall windows is open for out an in , I have static ip, I have the router D-link DSL 2500-E, the simulator is here http://suporte.dlink.com.br/suporte/emuladores/ADSL/dsl-2500E/emulador/fw-dmz.htm.

- Virtual Server (supposedly I can open all the ports that I want, but when I scan my public IP with nmap the ports are filtered :/ , I
  guess for the firewall and I don't find the point of this option if
  the firewall can't be disabled)
- I tried DMZ,ACL,Port triggering without success for the ports that i need.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Keep in mind that your ISP may block some incoming ports. I wouldn't be surprised if those ports were all blocked by your ISP - contact them or check on their web site for any information on port blocking.

Comment: my ISP is not blocking, because I can open the ports 21,23,80 with DMZ and ACL option by default but, I cant open ports 443,1243,3306 that I need :(

Comment: have you confirmed that you have services listening on those ports?

Comment: netstat -ano, It is listening at 10.0.0.6:3306 which is my local ip.